# xmllint capturing error code

Tags: xml, linux, error-handling, xmllint

I´m using the `xmllint` Linux command ([xmllint description](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)) and I want to capture the error code to use it inside a script. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can doing this :

```
if xmllint --xpath '/my/path' file.xml; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo >&2 "error"
    exit 1
fi
```

**If you don't have `--xpath` switch** :

```
file=/path/to/file
xpath='/foo/bar'
result="$(echo "cat $xpath" | xmllint --shell "$file")"

if [ $(echo "$result" | wc -l) -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo >&2 "error"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/5080881 Have you ever read the man page or the help ??? My script is fully working. If you don't understand something, ask.

Comment: Alphabetically, the last option of the man page, is --xmlout. That´s why I wrote that. Maybe we are using different versions of xmllint.

Comment: `xmllint: using libxml version 20800
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have schema that you want to validate your xml file with you can do this:
xmllint --noout --schema your_xsd_file your_xml_file 2>myxmlval.out

myxmlval.out will be a file that capture error that comes out from xmllint schema validation